# How can I save an image via API in Laravel Server from React Native

Tags: laravel, react-native, api, post

I am trying to save some info and an image sent through api from React Native app. This is the request that I get if I log it.

```
[2022-08-05 10:11:09] local.ERROR: array ('{
    "data":{
        "_parts":' => array ('[
            "image", {
                "modificationDate":"1659694264000","size":2883040,"mime":"image/jpeg","height":4160,"width":3120,"path":"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.wheeloffortune/files/Pictures/image-6ab1ad33-2580-416b-be7d-09a0662739218182247041115654861.jpg"
            }' => NULL,
        ),)
```

When I tested api from postman I get image as a file and have saved it easily without a sweat. But from the app the developer sends in the format I pasted above. Can I somehow save image from the above request.

Comment: You are not receiving the file via API. You are just receiving the info of the image and the location of the image on the local android device which is not accessible from your code. so the answer is No, you can't save it.

Comment: https://aboutreact.com/file-uploading-in-react-native/ this tutorial contains both server side code and react-native code. Though code written in laravel is not available there, but it would be helpful to understand the process.